# Detecte Automatically detect the subtitles of an MKV video (videojs or other)

Tags: javascript, web, auto, subtitle, mkv

I'm looking for a solution to detect the subtitles of an MKV video, in order to add them automatically in the player, but I can't find them after 2 weeks of research, I really hope you have a solution.

I use VideoJS, but if I have to use another solution, no problem!

The video player is on a web application.

Thank you to you!

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: FFMPEG, VideoJS Extension, JS Script